# Jira REST API idempotency

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api

I'm writing a software that interacts with Jira using REST API.

Are there any means to achieve idempotency of create issue request?

Or should I use a compensating action in case of detected duplicate?

Comment: Realistically, a Create event can never be idempotent by its very nature.

Answer (score 1):

Because JIRA uses an incremental integer suffix for tickets, calling a create action will always create a ticket with a new identifier, even if all else is equal.

In general, idempotence is patterned into the API itself and is particularly rare when creating a resource. If you try to mimic idempotence into your calling action, then you risk losing idempotence if the API changes. You're better off testing for duplicates and handling exceptions (again, as a generalization).

Comment: Yes, what I was asking for is if there is something in the API for idempotency, like some unique external key to pass in request.

Comment: I do know that in import, you can specify the issue number and thus enforce the kinds of consistency you are seeking. Perhapswe you can tie that into your solution?

Comment: Find something in your request that is unique and search for it in JIRA. There's no magic way that JIRA can tell if you are duplicating an existing issue.